A-Level physics question: gradient of graph of voltage
I am trying to do question 25(b) from this A-Level physics paper: (page 20/28)
https://ocr.org.uk/Images/677416-question-paper-breadth-in-physics.pdf

According to the mark scheme, the graph should be a curve of decreasing gradient starting at 1.5 and ending at 0: (page 15/17)
https://ocr.org.uk/Images/677433-mark-scheme-breadth-in-physics.pdf
I am not sure why though. Could someone explain to me why the gradient is decreasing?

This is what I tried:
Let $L=1$ for simplicity, so that $0 \le x \le 1$. Given that the resistance of both resistors are the same, the total resistance can be written as:
$$xR + \frac{(1-x)R^2}{R+(1-x)R}$$
Hence, by Ohm's law, the current in the circuit is:
$$\frac{1.5(2-x)}{R(1+x-x^2)}$$
So the voltage through the fixed resistor is:
$$V = \frac{1.5(1-x)}{1+x-x^2}$$
But $\dfrac{\mathrm d^2 V}{\mathrm d x^2} > 0$ for $x < \alpha$ where $\alpha \approx 0.6778$, so the gradient is increasing for $0 \le x \le \alpha$. It is only decreasing for $x > \alpha$.
Here is a plot showing $V(x)$ in green and $\dfrac{\mathrm d^2 V}{\mathrm d x^2} > 0$ in red:

So I am confused about why the mark scheme suggests the gradient is decreasing throughout the interval. I must have made an error in my maths but I cannot see it. Also, is there a way of interpreting this using physical principles without any mathematics? This question is aimed at 16 year olds who won't necessarily have studied calculus, so I presume this must be possible.

You are completely correct. The answer key is just stating what features they want to see in the plot before they would award full grades.

So the answer key is then wrong in requiring a curve of decreasing gradient, you mean!
(I was also surprised... But indeed, the gradient in this circuit topology is not decreasing everywhere. The voltage is of course decreasing.)

@JosBergervoet Yes, the OP is completely correct in every part of the derivation and so the correct answer must be the green line as plotted. The red line clearly shows that the answer key's required curvature behaviour is only for the right third.
